# To get Id of dropdown inside gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

In the below code i have a dropdown inside gridview i want to get id of the dropdown.In which i get object reference error.I tried the below code it throws error of object reference on page loading. Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
 $(document).ready(OnReady);

        function OnReady() {
           //Handle the change event for the drop down list
            $("#ddlLocation").change(onChange);
        }

        function onChange() {
            //create the ajax request
            $.ajax
            (
            {
                type: "POST", //HTTP method
                url: "NewIndent.aspx/OnContinentChange", //page/method name
                data: "{'continentName':'" + $("#<%=ddlLocation.ClientID%>").val() + "'}", //json to represent argument
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: callback,
                error: onError
            }
        );

        }

        //Handle the callback on success
        function callback(msg) {
            //it shows object object
             var val = msg.d;
             var countries = val.split(';');
             var length = countries.length;
             //var ID = gvProduct.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["ddlProduct"].ToString();
             document.getElementById('<%=gvProduct.FindControl("ddlProduct").ClientID%>').options.length = 0;
            // var Ier = gvProduct.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["ddlProduct"].ToString();
             var dropDown = document.getElementById('<%=gvProduct.FindControl("ddlProduct").ClientID%>');
            for (var i = 0; i < length - 1; ++i) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = countries[i];
                option.value = countries[i];

                dropDown.options.add(option);
            }
        }

        //Handle the callback on error
        function onError() {
            alert('something went wrong');
        }



 <asp:GridView Width="100%" runat="server" ID="gvProduct" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" ShowFooter="true"
                            PageSize-Mode="NumericPages" PageSize="10" PagerStyle-Visible="true" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"                            
                            CssClass="mGrid" OnRowDataBound="gvProduct_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="gvProduct_RowDeleting"
                            PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name" ItemStyle-Width="350px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" Style="width: 100%; height:23px" ></asp:DropDownList>                                                                             


                                    </ItemTemplate>                                   
                                </asp:TemplateField>
  </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You want the ID of _which_ `DropDownList` in a `GridView`? Every row in the grid contains that dropdown.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter yes i want to get id(ddlProduct) of dropdown inside grid.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter i want to get id= ddlProduct  of dropdown

Comment: But it's ID is different since it's sitting in a control which generates ID's according to the number of rows in the grid. That's why i'm asking which ID you actually want.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter i want to get all the rows id of dropdown which i am selecting a dropdown of a particular row.

Answer (score 0):

The `ddlProduct` is in a row in the `GridView`. If you have more than a single row in your `GridView`, there isn't a single `ddlProduct` but a whole bunch of them. They are all different. You will need to get the row first for which you want the value of `ddlProduct`.

Usually a `GridView` renders client-side as a `table`, with `tr`'s and `td`'s, so you would need to traverse the DOM to get to the dropdowlist.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jquery, why not attach a class name to your drop down list & use that for selection of your drop down list ? That would be much easier option than generating your scripts for all client ids in your grid.